# How to connect with kerberos with Ktor

Tags: kotlin, kerberos, ktor

Before developing an API with ktor, I would like to know if it's possible to authenticate to the API with kerberos. I didn't find a module to do it on ktor docs.

Comment: Ktor doesn't have an integration with Kerberos.

Comment: isn't it possible to use an other authentication to connect to kerberos ?

Comment: What do you mean?